# AppleTV interrupting while playing movie

Tags: appletv, hdmi

My new black Apple TV (3rd generation) is plugged into my flatscreen by HDMI. All worked fine.

A few days ago there were sudden "interruptions" while watching a show from netflix: no video, no sound, black screen. After a few seconds, video and sound returned, my screen shows a message that it is connected to a HDMI source.

From that message, I understand that the HDMI connection was lost. ATV has the latest software, the interruptions come and go, no pattern to be detected.

Anybody know what I can do, apart from returning the ATV and getting a new one?

Comment: is it still doing it or was it one time event?

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is still doing it, seemingly more often.

Comment: and you checked the hdmi cable

Comment: see if you can fix it http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203422

Comment: @Buscar going to check cable asap and post if it sold ed the issue, no post = no solution.

Comment: I think the article Buscar pointed you to is sending you down the correct path.  In reality you are most likely suffering from bandwidth/buffering issues.  The reason you see the HDMI messages on the screen is because as the video restarts the apple tv and tv are renegotiating what resolution and frequency sent along the cable.

Comment: Seems a different HDMI cable solved the issue, @Buscar웃! Amazing!

Comment: OK, lets make that a answer so you can mark it as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HDMI connection lost

Could mean that the HDMI cable is not having good contacts on the pins.

The only way to test that is to get different HDMI cable.

Apple also provides some [instruction](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203422) on how to fix it.